# Rename duplicate column name by order in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to rename two duplicate columns in consecutive order:

**Data**

```
DD  Nice Nice Hello
0   1    1    2
```

**Desired**

```
DD  Nice1 Nice2 Hello
0   1     1     2
```

**Doing**

```
df.rename(columns={"Name": "Name1", "Name": "Name2"})
```

I am running the `rename` function, however, because both column names are identical, the results are not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `itertools.count()` counter and a list expression to create new column headers, then assign them to the data frame.

For example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=["Nice", "Nice", "Hello"])
>>> df
   Nice  Nice  Hello
0     1     2      3
>>> count = itertools.count(1)
>>> new_cols = [f"Nice{next(count)}" if col == "Nice" else col for col in df.columns]
>>> df.columns = new_cols
>>> df
   Nice1  Nice2  Hello
0      1      2      3
```

(Python 3.6+ required for the f-strings)

**EDIT**: Alternatively, per the comment below, the list expression can replace any label that may contain `"Nice"` in case there are unexpected spaces or other characters:

```
new_cols = [f"Nice{next(count)}" if "Nice" in col else col for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: Hi thanks,this works partially, however the second name 'Nice' didn't get the number 2 added to it- I am troubleshooting

Comment: Is there possibly a column label with a space or other character in it? The list expression could be changed to use `if "Nice" in col` if it needs to be more flexible.

Comment: Ok perhaps there is a space , but I am not sure. Is there a way to add both use cases? ‘Nice’ and ‘Nice  ‘

Comment: @Lynn: I've updated the answer to include the way to replace any label containing "Nice".

Comment: this works - thank you

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach with `groupby`:

```
s = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.columns)


df.columns = np.where(s.transform('size')>1, 
                      df.columns + s.cumcount().add(1).astype(str), 
                      df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   DD  Nice1  Nice2  Hello
0   0      1      1      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
cols = pd.Series(df.columns)
dup_count = cols.value_counts()
for dup in cols[cols.duplicated()].unique():
    cols[cols[cols == dup].index.values.tolist()] = [dup + str(i) for i in range(1, dup_count[dup]+1)]

df.columns = cols
```

`Input:`

```
col_1  Nice  Nice  Nice  Hello  Hello  Hello
col_2     1     2     3      4      5      6
```

`Output:`

```
col_1  Nice1  Nice2  Nice3  Hello1  Hello2  Hello3
col_2      1      2      3       4       5       6
```

`Setup to generate duplicate cols:`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col_1':['Nice', 'Nice', 'Nice', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello'], 'col_2':[1,2,3,4, 5, 6]})
df = df.set_index('col_1').T
```